# Combine paths with Windows API when both paths may be relative

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to be able to combine two different Windows paths, both of which may be relative, into a single path (by applying the second as an extension of the first). It should not matter whether either path actually exists on the filesystem. Examples:

```
C:\abc + def -> C:\abc\def
C:\abc + ..\def -> C:\def
\\server\share + def -> \\server\share\def
..\some\path\abc + ..\def -> ..\some\path\def
..\some\path + ..\..\..\def -> ..\..\def
```

Ideally, it should also resolve drive-relative "absolute" paths (i.e. paths beginning with a single backslash) to the appropriate path on the given drive:

```
C:\abc + \def -> C:\def
```

Finally, it would be nice if it handled the case of the second path being absolute, by returning that absolute path:

```
C:\abc + D:\def -> D:\def
```

Another way of putting it is:

*I want a function that takes as arguments a path 'A' and a path 'B'. The output 'C' should be the same as if I called `SetCurrentDirectory` first with A and then with B and then called `GetCurrentDirectory` (however, it should not matter if the paths don't exist, and it should at no point change the current working directory, and the result should be a relative path if both A and B are relative paths; I do not particularly care if the result path contains '..' segments).*

The code needs to work on Windows 7. I've looked at the [shell path handling functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Windows API, but they don't seem suitable:

- for [PathAppend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the first path cannot be relative:

  > The path supplied in pszPath cannot begin with "..\" or ".\" to
  >   produce a relative path string. If present, those periods are stripped
  >   from the output string.
- for [PathCombine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),  the first path cannot be relative and cannot be a UNC path:

  > The directory path should be in the form of A:,B:, ..., Z:

(**Edit**: On closer inspection, that snippet of documentation seems like it might really belong to another function. The parameter names mentioned are not the same as the parameter names given in the method signature. In fact, as demonstrated in the second answer below, `PathCombine` does seem to work with UNC paths. However, it has the same problem that `PathAppend` does - in that it strips leading `..` segments from the output path).

- [PathCchCombine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [PathAllocCombine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are only available on Windows 8 and beyond.

Are there any standard functions that I've overlooked, or is there any library which correctly handles all cases including UNC-style paths? Or is there at least a simple way to implement a function which meets my requirements using others that are already available?

Comment: It sounds like you could use `PathAppend` and write a wrapper function that saves any leading period branches in the first path and restores them afterwards.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that might be a possibility, yes. I'm still hoping there might be a more elegant solution, but it's seeming less and less likely :(

Comment: `C:\abc + \def -> C:\def` is inconsistent with `C:\abc + D:\def -> D:\def`: In both cases the second path is absolute, but you wish to handle them differently. In the first example you may wind up with a path (`C:\def`) that doesn't exist, even though `\def` does.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I do want to handle them differently. The fact that MS documentation considers them both to be absolute paths does not mean that I want them both to be handled in the same way - I think the question is pretty clear about this.

Comment: Putting it another way, the second path should be _stateless_. Resolving it should not require the concept of a current drive or current directory.

Comment: Being clear doesn't make the requirement any more consistent. It's like asking *"I want to implement `operator+` that returns the sum of both arguments. If the second argument is negative, it should return the difference instead."* This is pretty clear, and not very consistent. If you want to handle certain absolute paths in a way that is inconsistent with documented semantics you should reject the input, instead of changing the semantics around. Imposing surprising restrictions makes this question less useful to the general audience.

Comment: @IInspectable with all due respect, this is my question and I'm asking for what I need. An "absolute" path that begins with a single backslash can only be resolved relative to an unspecified root (eg network share or drive letter). I'm saying that I want that root to be taken from the first path. This is not anywhere near as inconsistent as your contrived example with `operator+`. A more closely aligned example would have given the function an arbitrary name rather than `operator+`; then you see that there is nothing inconsistent.

Comment: @IInspectable I should note also that the `PathCombine` API function apparently handles absolute-sans-drive-letter paths in just the way I want (i.e. the way that you claim is inconsistent). So this requirement isn't as arbitrary as you seem to think; at least, it has been implemented elsewhere. I imagine the logic behind it is much the same as my logic for requiring this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef MAX_PATH
#define MAX_PATH 260
#endif

char *rootFolder(char *folder);

int IsFullPath(const char *p){
    if(p && *p){
        if(((*p>='A') && (*p<='Z')) ||((*p>='a') && (*p<='z'))){
            return  p[1]==':';
        }
        return *p=='\\' & p[1]=='\\';
    }
    return 0;
}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/
char *FolderUp(char *path,int deep){



    path=rootFolder(path);
    if(!*path) return path;

    int i=strlen(path);

    char *p=path;
    if(path[i-1]=='\\') path--;

    while(i &&(deep>0)){
         i--;
        if(path[i]=='\\'){
            p=&path[i+1];
            deep--;
        }
    }
    return  p;

}
/*_________________________________________________________________
*/
char *NextFolder(char *path){
    while(*path){
        path++;
        if(*path=='\\'){
            path++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return path;
}
/*_________________________________________________________________
*/
char *rootFolder(char *folder){
    char *p;
    if((*folder=='\\') && (folder[1]=='\\')){
        return NextFolder(&folder[2]);
    }

    if(*folder && folder[1]==':' && folder[2]=='\\')
        return &folder[3];
    return folder;
}


int chdir(/*IN_OUT*/char *curDir,const /*IN*/char *newDir){ 

    int deep=0,i;
    const char *p=newDir,*tmp;


    if(!newDir ||!*newDir ) return 0;

    if(IsFullPath(newDir)){
        strcpy(curDir,newDir);
        return 1;
    }

    if(*newDir=='\\'){
        tmp=rootFolder(curDir);
        if(*tmp!='\\') tmp--;
        strcpy(tmp,newDir);
        return 1;
    }

    /**/

    while(*p && (p[0]=='.' && p[1]=='.')) {
        if(p[2]!='\\') {
            deep=0;
            break;
        }
        p+=3;
        deep++;
    }
    if(deep){
        tmp=FolderUp(curDir,deep);
        if(tmp[-1]!='\\') p--;
        strcpy(tmp,p);
        return 1;
    }

    i=strlen(curDir);
    if(i && curDir[i-1]!='\\'){
        curDir[i]='\\';
        curDir[i+1]=0;
    }
    strcat(curDir,newDir);
    return 1;
    /**/
}

void DoTest(char *curDir,char *newDir){
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    strcpy(path,curDir);

    if(chdir(path,newDir))
        printf("'%s' + '%s' -> %'%s'\n",curDir,newDir,path);
    else
        printf("Error: an unhandled error occured\n");
    return ;

}
int main(){

    DoTest("C:\\abc","def");
    DoTest("C:\\abc","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("C:\\abc\\","def");
    DoTest("C:\\abc\\","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server\\share","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\share","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server\\share\\","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\share\\","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server\\","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("c:\\Folder","\\\\server\\share");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\share","c:\\Folder");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("..\\Folder\\sub folder","..\\sibling");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

```
'C:\abc' + 'def' -> 'C:\abc\def'
'C:\abc' + '..\def' -> 'C:\def'

'C:\abc\' + 'def' -> 'C:\abc\def'
'C:\abc\' + '..\def' -> 'C:\def'

'\\server\share' + 'def' -> '\\server\share\def'
'\\server\share' + '..\def' -> '\\server\def'

'\\server\share\' + 'def' -> '\\server\share\def'
'\\server\share\' + '..\def' -> '\\server\def'

'\\server' + 'def' -> '\\server\def'
'\\server' + '..\def' -> '\\server\def'

'\\server\' + 'def' -> '\\server\def'
'\\server\' + '..\def' -> '\\server\def'

'c:\Folder' + '\\server\share' -> '\\server\share'
'\\server\share' + 'c:\Folder' -> 'c:\Folder'

'..\Folder\sub folder' + '..\sibling' -> '..\Folder\sibling'
```

Comment: Test case when both paths are relative?  That's the focus of the question.

Comment: i added a test for two relative paths, and it passed

Comment: Right, this works - though it still boggles my mind that there's no pre-existing API function to do it. I'll accept in a day or two if no better answer comes through.

Comment: what is the bug you find in it, maybe i can resolve that

Comment: You misunderstood me, there's no bug, your answer is fine - it's just that I expected that there would be an API suitable for this. The problem is not in your answer, it's the API :)

Comment: You need to study [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx). Your implementation fails for several path syntaxes. Paths can have a *"\\?\"* prefix which you are unconditionally interpreting as an absolute path. The code also doesn't account for relative paths that contain a drive letter, e.g. `D:example.txt`.

Comment: @ IInspectable, indeed i need to study `Naming Files, Paths`, and `Namespaces`, amount all things you have studied and does you still didn't. I have right now provided two different codes. just because no one did. or maybe i have too much time to do.

Comment: what about \\DosDevice\ and embedded resources?

Comment: @IInspectable how can you 'cd' from dos console to a server shared folder as \\Server\Share. can you do it from console?

Comment: @IInspectable maybe I'm misunderstanding, I think the `\\?\\` prefix _does_ denote an absolute path? In any case I don't need to handle such paths so this answer is fine for my needs.

Comment: @davmac: You are right, the *"\\?\"* prefix cannot be used with relative paths. Still, there are way too many issues with the code posted in this answer to accept it (like failure to identify absolute paths without a drive letter). This answer may solve your immediate problem, but it is not an answer to the question asked, and shouldn't be accepted as the answer. You can still vote on it, if you find it helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable it handles all the "core" cases I specified, which is why I've accepted it. It doesn't handle the case you mention ("absolute" path without a drive letter), true. Can you see any other issues with it?

Comment: @davmac: It doesn't handle relative paths with a drive letter either (as pointed out already). It also doesn't handle cases, where `..` or `.` occurs inside the path string. That's not strictly part of your specification, but it seems likely, that that's what you want.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't see any sensible way of handling drive-relative paths for the 2nd path (I don't really want to resulting path to depend on the current working directory of any particular drive), other than returning them as-is - I think this code does that. The goal is to allow specification of a path from X to Y, either as a relative path from X or possibly as an absolute path for Y (where X may be absolute or may be any form of relative path). Collapsing `..` if it occurs mid-way through the 2nd relative path is a nice-to-have but not required. I don't like the style of this code...

Comment: ... much, but it seems like it satisfies my requirements and is the best answer posted.

Comment: @IInspectable "\\?\" is an absolute path, "\folder\sub folder" is an absolute path. check MSDN documentation

Answer (score 0):

this uses WINAPI functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
//#pragma lib "Shlwapi.lib" 
#pragma comment( lib  , "Shlwapi.lib"  )



char *rootFolder(char *folder);

int IsAbsolutePath(const char *p){
    return !PathIsRelative(p);
}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/

int chdir(/*IN_OUT*/char *curDir,const /*IN*/char *newDir){ 

    int deep=0,i;
    char *p=(char*) newDir,*tmp;


    if(!newDir ||!*newDir ) return 0;

    /*if(IsAbsolutePath(newDir)){
        strcpy(curDir,newDir);
        return 1;
    }*/
    return (int) PathCombine(curDir,curDir,newDir);

    /**/
}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/

void DoTest(char *curDir,char *newDir){
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    strcpy(path,curDir);

    if(chdir(path,newDir))
        printf("'%s' + '%s' -> %'%s'\n",curDir,newDir,path);
    else
        printf("Error: an unhandled error occured\n");
    return ;

}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/

int main(){

    DoTest("C:\\abc","def");
    DoTest("C:\\abc","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("C:\\abc\\","def");
    DoTest("C:\\abc\\","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server\\share","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\share","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server\\share\\","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\share\\","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("\\\\server\\","def");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\","..\\def");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("c:\\Folder","\\\\server\\share");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\share","c:\\Folder");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("c:\\Folder","\\share");
    DoTest("\\\\server\\share","\\Folder");
    printf("\n");

    DoTest("..\\Folder\\sub folder","..\\sibling");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output

```
'C:\abc' + 'def' -> 'C:\abc\def'
'C:\abc' + '..\def' -> 'C:\def'

'C:\abc\' + 'def' -> 'C:\abc\def'
'C:\abc\' + '..\def' -> 'C:\def'

'\\server\share' + 'def' -> '\\server\share\def'
'\\server\share' + '..\def' -> '\\server\def'

'\\server\share\' + 'def' -> '\\server\share\def'
'\\server\share\' + '..\def' -> '\\server\def'

'\\server' + 'def' -> '\\server\def'
'\\server' + '..\def' -> '\\def'

'\\server\' + 'def' -> '\\server\def'
'\\server\' + '..\def' -> '\\def'

'c:\Folder' + '\\server\share' -> '\\server\share'
'\\server\share' + 'c:\Folder' -> 'c:\Folder'

'c:\Folder' + '\share' -> 'c:\share'
'\\server\share' + '\Folder' -> '\\server\share\Folder'

'..\Folder\sub folder' + '..\sibling' -> 'Folder\sibling'
```

Comment: While this does seem to work, you're using `PathCombine` which is documented as requiring a drive-letter based path for the 2nd argument.

Comment: Also this is an incorrect result: `'..\Folder\sub folder' + '..\sibling' -> 'Folder\sibling'`

Comment: yes i know, i just demonstrated how WINAPI handle such situations. for that reasons i provided the previous code (self made).