# alternatives to functions PathCombine() and PathCchCombine()

Tags: winapi, windows-7

i am coding for windows 7 and windows 10 and want to have only a single main binary for my application.

In this application i want to join a path and a file name so that all relative path specs are eliminated.
Now i found out that when using PathCombine() function i am portable but the function itself has the chance by design to create buffer overrun issues under certain input conditions.
For PathCchCombine() the security is improved by an extra parameter providing the results buffer size but its not available on the first mentioned platform (the function is only there on Win8 or higher - maybe provided with api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll or just by the Windows KernelBase.dll).

How to solve that so that i can keep a single binary, don't need to provide extra DLLs and still stay save against buffer overruns?
Is there some alternate function for Windows 7 that will just serve me?

Comment: [PathCombine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew) doesn't exhibit the potential for a buffer overrun *"by design"*. It only exhibits a buffer overrun when *"misused"*, by providing an output buffer that is too small. If you pass an output buffer that is large enough, there will be no buffer overrun. You know the maximum length of the output (length of `pszDir` + length of `pszFile` + 1 for the potentially added path separator).

Comment: i am not sure if the input buffers will have MAX_PATH or fewer chars, either alone or combined after the various path string adjustments. MAX_PATH is not the limit on real world systems. Cch functions ofthen set the limit to PATHCCH_MAX_CCH that is defined to 0x8000 = 32 kB.

Comment: thanks for pointing onto the difference the docu sees for a wording of misuse and design. actually i dont think MSVC compiler will ever warn me if passing a buffer that has less than MAX_PATH chars and neither at runtime i expect any mechanism beeing able to catch such an error case. Cch design is superior, but what good option do i have to use such an API feature with all the mentioned Windows versions?

Comment: after a bit more of research i feel like i jumped into an old but large pit about many applications having a built in path limit of MAX_PATH=260 - even today.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc85630e-5684-4df6-ad2f-5a128de3deef/260-character-explorer-path-length-limit?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: found this question on paths and combining them with the api call i mentioned. the answers ended up in self-written codes - along with many question marks on completeness and conformance of the code proposals.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150102/combine-paths-with-windows-api-when-both-paths-may-be-relative

Comment: Where is the problem in dynamically allocating a buffer for `pszDest` parameter of `PathCombine` that has the required size, which @IInspectable has described?

Comment: PathCombine is limited to MAX_PATH - PathCchCombine allows a lot more chars. somehow i hoped that if there is a flexible size function i can just provide a larger buffer at any time and _in_case of Win10 it will be used as it is whilst on Win7 the system's limit will just "clip" to what the system can do. as of now i see i can only have the lower limit for both - because the API common between both version does not scale even if the platform would support it.

Comment: If you can use C++17 or boost, you could use `std::filesystem::path` or `boost::filesystem::path` instead. AFAIK these don't impose `MAX_PATH` limits. Both have `append()` and `operator/=` methods for combining paths. They are also safer to use, because you don't need to do manual buffer management.

Comment: You could just write the function yourself, it doesn't really do anything particularly difficult or magical.

Answer (score 0):

indicated solution:

i need to use PathCombine() becaue its the only option that works on Win7.

i have to supply a results buffer of MAX_PATH (smaller is risky, bigger is useless).

i have to accept that even if Win10 might support path length of 32kB or more there is no simple solution (like a single API call) that will work with any of the platform determined limits and/or content determined results length. - there are function variants (thinking of PathAllocCanonicalize) that do dynamic allocations and thus the caller does not need any pre-result knowledge, but all of these functions seem to be available only with Win8 or higher.